# Drawing a hat with C#

Tags: c#, loops

After an hour of headaches, I finally figured out how to draw the hat on the console. However, now I'm having a hard time connecting the left and right part of the hat. I assume I did all the necessary calculations so they don't have to be checked. I tried to connect them using nested loops but I messed up even more. Here's what I did so far (enter a number to start the program):

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //top of hat
        Console.Write(new string('.', 2 * n - 1));
        Console.Write("/|\\");
        Console.Write(new string('.', 2 * n - 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(new string('.', 2 * n - 1));
        Console.Write("\\|/");
        Console.Write(new string('.', 2 * n - 1));
        Console.WriteLine();

        //middle left
        for (int i = 2 * n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
             Console.Write(new string('.', i));
             Console.Write("*");
             Console.Write(new string('-', n * 2 - i - 1));
             Console.Write("*");
             Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //middle right
        for (int m = 0; m < 2 * n - 1; m++)
        {
            Console.Write(new string('-', m));
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.Write(new string('.', n * 2 - m - 2));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //bottom
        Console.Write(new string('*', 4 * n + 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int p = 0; p < 2 * n; p++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.Write(".");
        }
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(new string('*', 4 * n + 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
```

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSwul.png)

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUA94.png)

Comment: Could you show an example of what the correct hat should look like, and what the program's current output is?

Comment: You really should learn the basics of coding. Here: Learn how to break the problem down to small reusable functions. Here: Learn how to draw a line; then a filled rectangle, an ellispe a filled one. With these primitives the task will be trivial as will be the furure ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle left part and the middle right part should be inside the same loop before the `Console.WriteLine()`, because they have to be drawn on the same line.

If you draw them in 2 consecutive loops each of the containing WriteLines they will be drawn on top of each other.

Take the 3 first Writes in the middle left loop, inverse their order and add them before the WriteLine. Drop the middle right loop. Done!

Also, if you replace all the `'.'` (excepted in the bottom part) by `' '`, you'll get a better look. Also, add `Console.Write("n = ");` as the first statement in order to get an input prompt.

```
n = 3
     /|\
     \|/
     ***
    *-*-*
   *--*--*
  *---*---*
 *----*----*
*-----*-----*
*************
*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*************
```

If you write a function for lines like

```
Console.Write(new string('.', i));
```

your code will become more readble:

```
private static void Draw(char c, int count = 1)
{
    Console.Write(new string(c, count));
}
```

then

```
Console.Write(new string(' ', 2 * n - 1));
```

becomes simply

```
Draw(' ', 2 * n - 1);
```

Note also that the `count` parameter is optional and has a default value of one. So if you need to draw exactly one character, you can write

```
Draw('*');
```